# Excel VBA - in a list, if cell equals specific value then

Tags: vba, excel

I started working on some code, and it works, but I feel like it could be done more effiently. Below is a portion of it to show what I'm doing. To simplify the idea, I've made it here so if the cell in column M is A, B, or C, it puts a 1 in column L. If column M is a D, E, or F, it puts a 2 in column L. And if column M is a G, H, or I, it puts a 3 in column L.

Is there an easier way to do this than how I'm doing it? I'm going to be dealing with a couple hundred possible values.

```
Sub ChangeTest()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    LastRow = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Range("M" & i).Value = "A" Or Range("M" & i).Value = "B" Or Range("M" & i).Value = "C" Then
        Range("L" & i).Value = "1"
        End If
        If Range("M" & i).Value = "D" Or Range("M" & i).Value = "E" Or Range("M" & i).Value = "F" Then
        Range("L" & i).Value = "2"
        End If
        If Range("M" & i).Value = "G" Or Range("M" & i).Value = "H" Or Range("M" & i).Value = "I" Then
        Range("L" & i).Value = "3"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This would be a case for codereview.stackexchange.com. Check out `Select Case` for this kind of task. However it depends how your cases look like if you have several hundred.

Comment: If there are 200+ values I'd consider building a reference table in a s/sheet and then doing a lookup on that.